# Flutter. how to make one edge of a container cut in concave/crescent shape

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

this is a container with rounded edges :

```
new Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 50,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.lime,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(5)),
      ),
    )
```

I want to have the right side edge of the container concaved/crescent, as if it was cut using a half circle

something like this :

[image: flutter custom shaped container]

Thank you

Comment: make a class that extends [ShapeBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ShapeBorder-class.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily make this view using ArcView [link](https://github.com/figengungor/clippy_flutter). See attached image

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  child: Center(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: 3,
          child: Arc(
            arcType: ArcType.CONVEY,
            height: 10.0,
            clipShadows: [ClipShadow(color: Colors.black)],
            child: new Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 150,
               borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: new Radius.circular(5),
                  topRight: new Radius.circular(5),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lime,
          onPressed: null,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }
```

[image]